# react data fetching interval with priority

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I am currently developing react application to visualize lots of images.

At the beginning, it does not require to display images.
But, there are some images that could be needed in the near future. 
Those images are first requested using redux, axios and mongodb.

However, as there are still a lot of requests, it freezes overall application.

I wonder if there is a way to handle this problem such that requesting candidate images without hurting the overall performance (maybe as background tasks or with priority).

EDIT.

Those images are requested from renderBin react class. It renders svg shapes or an image based on its type in its props. It usually first renders a shape and later it turns into an image based on user interaction. Note that there is an upper class that calls multiple  to render multiple bins on the svg. I want to fetch images before it actually gets the user interaction and displays those images.

```
class RenderBin extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
        id: _.uniqueId('bin_'),
        src: null,
        srcUrl: null
      };
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       const {imagePool, getThumbnails, src} = this.props;
       if (imagePool[src]) {
          this.setState({src: src, srcUrl: imagePool[src]});
          return;
       }
       getThumbnails(src);
   }

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       const {imagePool, src, getThumbnails} = nextProps;
       const oldSrc = this.state.src;
       if (oldSrc === src) {
          if (imagePool[src]) {
              this.setState({src: src, srcUrl: imagePool[src]});
          }
       } else {
          if (imagePool[src]) this.setState({src: src, srcUrl: imagePool[src]});
          else getThumbnails(src);
       }
   }

   renderCircle = (...) => {...}
   renderRect = (...) => {...}
   renderImage = (x,y,w,h) => {
       return (
           <image href={this.state.srcUrl} x={x} y={y} width={w} height={h}
       );
   }

   render() {
       switch(this.props.type) {
           case 'rect': return this.renderRect(...);
           case 'circ': return this.renderCirc(...);
           case 'img': return this.renderImage(...);
       }
   }
}
```

In the getThumnails function, it requests an image as follows.

```
export function getThumbnails(fn) {
   return function(dispatch){
      axios.get('/api/image/thumbnails/' + fn)
           .then(function(response){
               dispatch({
                   type: "GET_THUMBNAILS",
                   payload: {
                     name: fn,
                     url: '/api/image/thumbnails' + fn
                   }
               })
           })
           .catch(function(err){
               dispatch({
                  type: "GET_THUMBNAILS_REJECTED",
                  payload: err
               })
           });
   };
}
```

In the image reducer, it update the imagePool as follows:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {imagePool:{}};

function getThumbnails(state, payload){
    const {name, url} = payload;
    if (state.image[name] === undefined) {
        const img = {[name]: url};
        return {...state, imagePool: {...state.imagePool, ...img}};
    }
    return state;
}

export function imgReducers(state=INITIAL_STATE, action) {
     const {type, payload} = action;
     switch(type) {
         case "GET_THUMBNAILS": return getThumbnails(state, payload);
         default: return state;
     }
}
```

EDIT 2 (current solution)
I could improve the performance a little bit (at least it doesn't freeze the application out so far).

My approach is to have two lists to store pended and on-going requests. The action to fetch an image is first added to a list storing all image requests (so-called, pendedRequest). One of the pended requests is then pushed to the other list storing all requests on-going, so-called underRequest. When the request is completed, the corresponding item is removed from the underRequest list. This actually helps to avoid having duplicated requests. Lastly, I set two configuration parameters to avoid heavy network traffic. One is to limit the number of on-going requests and the other is to set a delay in firing an action (or a request). The modified code is as below.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import config from '../../config';

const pendedRequest = []; // a list of pended requests
const underRequest = [];  // a list of on-going requests

export function getThumbnails(fn) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.get('/api/image/thumbnails/' + fn)
             .then(function(response){
                  // remove completed request from the underRequest list
                  let idx = underRequest.indexOf(fn);
                  if (idx > -1) underRequest.splice(idx,1);

                  // dispatch an action to update imagePool
                  ... (same as above) ...
             })
             .catch(...(same as above)...);
    };
}

// function used in RenderBin class
export function getThumbnailAsync(fn) {
     return dispatch => {
         // if it is on-going, discard the request
         if (underRequest.indexOf(fn) > -1) return;

         // if it is not in the pended requests, add the request
         if (pendedRequest.indexOf(fn) === -1) pendedRequest.push(fn);

         // if there are more than 'threshold' on-going actions,
         // then will come later
         if (underRequest.length > config.IMAGE_MAX_REQUEST) return;

         // consumes one of requests in the pendedRequest
         const pended = pendedRequest.shift();
         underRequest.push(pended);

         // delay the execution proportional to the length of on-going requests
         // to avoid heavy network traffic 
         setTimeout(() => {
             dispatch(getThumbnails(pended))
         }, config.THUMBNAIL_TIMEOUT * underRequest.length);
     };
}
```

I am going to modify a bit to replace pendedRequest with the priority queue. So that, an image with higher priority can be fetched first or requests in lower priority can be fetched earlier when same requests come with higher priority.

Any opinions on this approach would be very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you waiting for the images when you request them? Or using some form of Asynchronous call? Also could you please include some of the code where you do this?

Comment: @MichaelHancock I added part of the codes in the application. Thanks.